# Return a zip file from nodejs function

Tags: javascript, node.js, zip

I have a `nodejs` microservice, where I `zip` a folder containing 3 files which have been created by the code.

Now, i need to send this zip file as `response` when my service gets a `curl request`. I read through similar questions but they suggest how to download on client side, not sure how to use them here.

My nodejs code is :

```
var zipper = require('zip-local'); 
app.post("/checkFunc", function(req, res) {
    zipper.sync.zip("./finalFiles").compress().save("pack.zip");
    // so now the zip is created and stored at pack.zip
    console.log("Hello);
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream' });   

    //res.send(a); //not sure how to send the zip file, if I know the path of the zip file. 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the path of the zip then you can create a readable stream using `fs.createReadStream()` and use `pipe()` to pass the data from the stream directly to the response.

```
const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs')
const port = process.env.PORT || 1337
const zipper = require('zip-local')

const app = express()

app.post('/checkFunc', (req, res) => {
    // If you're going to use synchronous code then you have to wrap it
    // in a try/catch if you don't want to crash your server. In this case
    // I'm just handling the error and returning back a 500 error with a 
    // standard response message of Internal Server Error. You could do more
    //
    // Using the Error Handling Middleware (err, req, res, next) => {}
    // you can create a more robust error handling setup.
    // You can read more about that in the ExpressJS documentation.
    try {
      zipper.sync.zip("./finalFiles").compress().save("pack.zip");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('An error occurred zipping', err)
      return res.sendStatus(500)
    }

    // Create a readable stream that we can pipe to the response object
    let readStream = fs.createReadStream('./finalFiles/pack.zip')

    // When everything has been read from the stream, end the response
    readStream.on('close', () => res.end())

    // Pipe the contents of the readStream directly to the response
    readStream.pipe(res)
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on ${port}`))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and the comments about the synchronous code. surely valuable. I didnt realise i could send it as a normal file via readStream.